# C# Windows api codepack - Getting the target of a shortcut that points to a PIDL

Tags: c#, windows, shell, winapi

I'm trying to get the appusermodelid (aumid) of a specific process (program A), so that program B can use SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID() and then add tasks to program A's jumplist.

This works well if I set the aumid to for example MSEdgeDev, the problem is getting a target process's aumid. Currently, I'm using this code to enumerate the shell:appsfolder items to get the exe path and aumid of each installed program, then finding a matching exe path and getting the matching aumid.

```
var FOLDERID_AppsFolder = new Guid("{1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58}");
        ShellObject appsFolder = (ShellObject)KnownFolderHelper.FromKnownFolderId(FOLDERID_AppsFolder);
        Process target = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
        foreach(var app in (IKnownFolder)appsFolder)
        {
            string name = app.Name;
            string aumid = app.Properties.System.AppUserModel.ID.Value;
            string path = app.Properties.System.Link.TargetParsingPath.Value;

            if (target.MainModule.FileName == path)
                dosomething();
        }
```

This works for some programs, but others are shortcuts that don't have a file target. Is there any way I can get the actual target of those shortcuts? Or is there a better way to get the aumid for a specific process?

Edit:
These are the types of shortcuts i'm having issues with:
[Example shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mwgM.png)

I'm looking for a way to get the actual target exe of these shortcuts.

Comment: *" but others are shortcuts that don't have a file target."* For example? Whether it's just about the way you compare 2 strings, you need a case insensitive comparison method, such as: `if (String.Compare(path, target.MainModule.FileName, true)==0)`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT sorry I should've been more clear. I'm talking about shortcuts that don't show a target path at all, I've added an edit to the post with an example.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to injected `GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` into the specified process.

Comment: For the example you provided, it is feasible to compare `app.Name` with process name.